# "We could see the lava slowly advancing towards the town just ten miles away"

Tags: participle-clauses

> “We could see the lava slowly advancing towards the town just ten miles away.”

I picked up this sentence from an English book. I wonder why it doesn't need the verb *to be*:

> “We could see the lava **is** slowly advancing towards the town just ten miles away.”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence

> We could see the lava slowly advancing towards the town just ten miles
>   away

is grammatically correct. The part beginning with "slowly advancing.." is called *participial clause*. It is built around the participle *advancing*. We could rephrase it as

> We could see *that* the lava *was* slowly advancing towards the town just ten miles
>   away

To do this, as you see, we would need to add **that** ([not](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv336.shtml) strictly necessary; see J.R.'s examples) and **was**, thus turning it into a *[subordinate clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_clause)*. This one would be built around the verb *to be*, with the [subordinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_%28grammar%29#Subordinating_conjunctions) *that* connecting it to the main clause.

Note that we use *to be* as *was* (past tense) in the subordinate clause, according to a set of conventions called "[sequence of tenses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_of_tenses)" (Wikipedia), also covered [here](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/sequence.htm). We do this to make the verb agree with the past tense of "could see".

Comment: In your example, *that* is not a relative pronoun but a subordinator, indicating that the finite clause "the lava is slowly advancing ..." is a subordinate clause.

Comment: I agree with @snailplane. In that sentence, `that` is a conjuction. See the examples of use for the conjuction `that` in the [Oxford dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/that?q=that)

Comment: Also, in order to be correct, it needs to have "was" instead of "is".

Comment: Thanks for the corrections, @snailplane, Hellion, Nico! I was too rash in answering without reading up on this thoroughly. I will read up and fix the answer.

Answer (score 2):

We don't need a verb because we are merely describing what we could see:

> We could see the car.
>   We could see the car moving toward us.

A *"to be"* verb **could** be used, but I would usually use *was* with *could*, and *is* with *can*:

> We could see the lava.
>   We could see the lava advancing towards the town.
>   We could see the lava was advancing towards the town.
>   We can see the lava is advancing towards the town.

Answer (score 0):

"Towards" means that the distance between the town and the lava is getting smaller. "Forward" doesn't give a frame of reference that includes both the lava and the town, it just means moving towards the front (the front of what?). "Toward" means to move in the direction **of** (in this case in the direction of the town).

Just FYI, "advancing" is a verb. "Towards" is a preposition like "under" or "through". Forward is an adverb, modifying "advancing". The word can also be used as an adjective (the forward deck of the boat), a verb (I will forward the letter), even a noun (a position on a sports team).

Comment: I believe user2747502 means the verb *to be* (I've edited his/her post accordingly).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. S/he is apparently wanting to know why "toward" is preferable to "forward", neither of which are verbs in the sentence in question.

Comment: Where would you want to fill in "to be"?